# Why is this HTTP code not returning any data?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a Node.JS project and I'm trying to make an HTTP request to an API. I'm trying to debug this code and can't figure out why 'responseData' isn't being set.

```
var responseData = "initial";
var options = {
    hostname:'api.insight.ly',
    path: '/v2.1/contacts', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic (API key here)',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
};
http.get(options, (response) => {
    const statusCode = response.statusCode;
    let error;
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                        `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
    }
    if (error) {
        responseData = "ERROR";
        // consume response data to free up memory
        response.resume();
        return;
    }
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => {
    try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
        responseData = parsedData
    } catch (e) {
        responseData = e.message;
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    responseData = (`Got error: ${e.message}`);
  });
response.end(responseData);
```

I believe I have handled every case for errors and that no matter what, responseData should become an error or JSON data. However, at the end of this function `responseData` is initial. What am I missing?

Comment: Because `http.get` is an async call - move your `response.end` inside the `http.get` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a scope/closure issue, and are misunderstanding the Javascript event loop. This code does not run in the order that you declare it. You declare and assign the `responseData` variable at the first line. Then you declare options. Then you tell the `http` core module to initiate a GET request with those options, and provide it with a callback `(response)=>{...}`. Then you pass `responseData` to `response.end`. At this level of scope, `response` doesn't even exist; it is passed as an argument to the callback that you provided the `http.get` method. The event listeners (`response.on('data'...`,`response.on('end'...`) are where the real action is.

Your code is really executing in an order like this:

```
-> assign responseData
-> assign options
-> call http.get
-> call response.end with responseData
-> call http.get callback
-> set response.on 'data' callback
-> set response.on 'end' callback
-> call response.on 'data' callback with chunk1
-> call response.on 'data' callback with chunk2
-> etc...
-> call response.on 'end' callback
-> parse responseData
```

In fact, I don't think you even really need a `response.end` call, that seems more necessary if you are crafting a response to be sent *from* your server, where as you are really just looking to accumulate data from the response sent by another API. What you really need is a function to pass the accumulated `responseData` at the end of your 'end' event.

```
var responseData = "initial";
var options = {
    hostname:'api.insight.ly',
    path: '/v2.1/contacts', 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic (API key here)',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
};
http.get(options, (response) => {
    const statusCode = response.statusCode;
    let error;
    if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                        `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
    }
    if (error) {
        responseData = "ERROR";
        // consume response data to free up memory
        response.resume();
        return;
    }
      response.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
    response.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
    response.on('end', () => {
    try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
        responseData = parsedData
        //do something with your data here
    } catch (e) {
        responseData = e.message;
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
    responseData = (`Got error: ${e.message}`);
  });
```